Zebra ZD621R - ZPL command to rewind one label
I have a Zebra ZD621R printer.
I can see that the "mechanism" can rewind / back-feed one label.
Is there a ZPL command that I could use to force the mechanism to rewind / back-feed one label?

Have you looked in the ZPL Guide?

Yes I did. I made some tests. None of them was successful.

Which tests did you do/which command(s) did you try? Just so we don't suggest the same. Also from this manual page 143, it seems the "rewind" is more linked to an external/optional collection method and not the printer itself, as per ZPL Guide ^MM command note - page 246.
